# Integrate BooleanExpression into SQL query

Tags: sql, entitymanager, boolean-expression, mysema

this is my situation :

```
BooleanExpression be = //a certain BooleanExpression;
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
List<Tuple> result = (List<Tuple>) em.createQuery("select x from y where" + be);
```

What i would like to do is to take my BooleanExpression and to calculate it into the "where"...any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could you give us an example?

Comment: @PeterRing example :
`//com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression
BooleanExpression be =person.office.isNull().and(person.status.eq(PersonStatus.OK));
List<Person> people = em.createNativeQuery("select * from person as p WHERE BE") // where be = where office is not null and status = 'OK' `

what i would like to do is to integrate my boolexpr "be" into my query using it as a string